# Angular 6 default route not loading. How can I fix this?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-router, angular-module

I have an angular 6 project structured like bellow...

```
src
|- app
|  |- core
|  |  |- layout.component.ts/html/scss
|  |  |- core.module.ts
|  |- views
|  |  |- modules
|  |  |  |- sample
|  |  |  |  |- sample.component.ts/html/scss
|  |  |  |  |- sample-routing.module.ts
|  |  |  |  |- sample.module.ts
|- app.component.ts/html/scss
|- app-routing.module.ts
|- app.module.ts
```

...with the routing structure for sample module looking like...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: SampleComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SampleRoutingModule { }
```

...and app routing module looking like...

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'sample',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'sample',
        loadChildren: './views/sample/sample.module#SampleModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The behavior I'm noticing is that when I serve the app, the default base route that is supposed to be the `layout component` does not load. Instead I get a white screen with no errors in the console. Then if I type in `http://localhost:4200/sample` i get the correct behavior. Still that initial redirect is not happening that should load the layout component with the sample module within it. `app.component.html` has the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` as well as the `layout.component.html` Have been looking at this trying to figure it out for longer than i care to admit. Perhaps the location of the layout component is more important than I think so it should be registered to the app module?

Comment: Can you remove children from AppRoutingModule and confirm it works, or rename the path? I assume its because children path: '' equals to the parent path: ''

Comment: Plus path can't be empty for lazyloaded routes... There is well knows issue with it... You can google it.

Comment: I removed children from AppRoutingModule assuming it would just load the layout with no content...still nothing, white screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a `RouterModule` imported and `routes` defined in an old unrelated module within the same project with a default route. Something like...

```
const routes = {
  {
     path: '',
     component: RandomComponent
  }
}
...
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)]
...
```

Removing that fixed the routing I was trying to implement. Angular must have been trying to register some eager locations. Feel kinda dumb about it to be honest. Thanks to those who answered!

Answer (score 0):

Your child path is same as your parent path

```
 path: '',
component: LayoutComponent,
children: [
  {
    path: '/sample',//changed this 
    redirectTo: 'sample',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

Comment: Don't think that is the case. Since I have a layout component, the default route first loads that, then it loads the children through the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` of the layout component with the default route redirecting to the sample route (the lazy-loaded sample module). For completeness I tried it your way in case I really couldn't see the forest from the tress...it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an issue with the `redirectTo` being ignored in a lazy loaded routes.

Either ways, with the configuration that you have, you can do redirection within your child route itself.

sample.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'sample',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'sample',
        component: SampleComponent,
      },

    ]
  }
];
```

And app.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './views/sample/sample.module#SampleModule'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```